# Parse cloud code send flag to save object

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I've been trying to send a flag to save request. This save request is sent from different platforms so we seperated them with a flag. The problem is that it gives

```
Result: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

when you send the request to table without the parameter. I did not want to add this parameter as a column in the table but it seems it automatically creates it when you successfully save the object. Is there a way to save the object without creating the flag column and seperate the save requests with and without the flag? Thank you in advance.

```js
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("MessageTest", function(request, response) { 
        if(!request.object.get("fromMessages")) {
          ..
          ..
        }
        else response.succcess();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try to save an object directly from your app, you cannot remove the field from your request in `beforeSave` trigger. A better approach is to save your object via a Cloud function instead. Send in your object alongside of your platform flag to a cloud function, then construct a `MessageTest` object from the parameters (obviously ignoring your platform flag) and then save it from there.